# I can't compile Objective-C in GNUStep with Windows 7

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

I am trying to compile the following simple Objective-C code in GNUStep with Windows 7.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
        NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        NSLog (@"hello world");
        [pool drain];
        return 0;
}
```

I compile it using the following command line:

```
$ gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -L /GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries hello.m -o hello -lgnustep-base -lobjc
```

It doesn't compile, and I get the following error:

> sh: gcc : command not found

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How is your development environment set up – what do you have installed? `gcc: command not found` would indicate you forgot to install something or did it wrongly.

Comment: I already install two require file.also Core file.

Comment: If this were a unix machine , I would say that the Shell does not know about gcc yet.  Either you have to reload shell configuration or you need to add gcc to your search path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: required software components]

you have to install all the above components then you are good to go u can use foundantion.h